# What is a proper way to add rows with indices into sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite

I created a table by following query:

```
with sqlite3.connect('example.db', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES) as conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Surveys(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT, Desc TEXT, DictObject BLOB, Hash TEXT)")
    conn.commit()
```

Now I have to add some `Survey` data to `Surveys` table for every request. `Surveys` table has `Id` as primary integer value. This has to be increased upon every insertion - And What is the proper way to do it? Do I have to fetch every row and check what the last`Id`is upon every request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sqlite` will [automatically provide an id for a INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column](http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) on INSERT on a table if you do not provide a value yourself. Just insert data for every column *except* for the `id` column.

```
with sqlite3.connect('example.db', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES) as conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Surveys(Name, Desc, DictObject, Hash) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?",
        ('somename', 'some description\nof sorts\n',
         "{'dump': 'of a dictionary'}", '0xhash'))
```

You may want to add the keyword `AUTOINCREMENT` to your `id` column though; the default is to pick the highest existing row id plus 1, and if you delete data from the table on a regular basis that can lead to reuse of ids (delete the current highest id and it'll be re-used next time round). `AUTOINCREMENT` guarantees that each generated number will only be used once for a table, independent of deletes.

Note that when you use [a `sqlite3` connection as a context manager](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager) (using the `with` statement), the `commit()` is automatically applied for you. Quoting the documentation:

> Connection objects can be used as context managers that automatically commit or rollback transactions. In the event of an exception, the transaction is rolled back; otherwise, the transaction is committed.

In other words, you can safely *remove* the `conn.commit()` line in your code, it is entirely redundant.